# What's a good way to provide a searchable interface to Mailman mailing list archives?

Tags: email, search, mailing-list, mailman

If you have a collection of mailing list archives from Mailman (example [here](http://mail.hdfgroup.org/pipermail/hdf-forum_hdfgroup.org/)) is there a good way to make them searchable from a web-based interface?

Answer (score 3):

i've used  [htdig](http://www.htdig.org)  for this task with several different mailing list programs - majordomo, ecartis, and mailman.

htdig can be used with Mailman's own pipermail, but i find the combination of  [mhonarc](http://www.mhonarc.org/)  (to create a nice browsable archive - IMO far better/more flexible than pipermail) and htdig to be particularly good.

Answer (score 1):

Make it public, and then just let google index them. You can even make a google custom search that will search just your website.

Google do search quite well, and it's completly headache free.

Comment: I only want to search the mailing list archives.

Comment: And those archives ARE public and google doesn't appear to index them.  A search using keywords from an email that I would think would be unambiguous turns up nothing.

Comment: Use a custom google search if you want to only search your mailing list. If it's not picking it up, check your robots.txt.

Try setting up a custom google search and see what it says to check that google is indexing it.